# Not able to send mail to group email id

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I'm using smtp (c#)and trying to send mail to group id(official id) but its not able to send mail.Although through same code I'm able to send mail to individual id. Any idea what could be wrong here. 
Following code I'm using

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.To = "group@company.com";
mail.From = "me@company.com";
mail.Subject = "Test Mail: please Ignore";
mail.Body = body;
SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "mailhub.int.company.com";
SmtpMail.Send(mail)
```

I'm getting following error in my mail box:

```
Delivery has failed to these recipients or distribution lists:

group@company.com
Not Authorized. You are not authorized to send to this recipient or distribution list. For distribution lists please check approved senders in the corporate directory.

  _____  

Sent by Microsoft Exchange Server 2007    

Diagnostic information for administrators:

Generating server: GSPWMS005.int.company.com

group@company.com
#550 5.7.1 RESOLVER.RST.AuthRequired; authentication required ##
```

From error I could get an idea that some authentication is missing but not sure which one or how to resolve it.
If I send mail to this group thorough my outlook then its working ok.

Comment: Your exchange server requires authentication - you would need to code it to login as you, or a service account they have agreed to.

Comment: Assuming you don't require authentication?  Exchange 2007 by default sets distribution groups to not be allowed sending from anonymous sources which was probably not your intent.  You'll have to go in and set the group to receive mail from everyone: [How do I make an Exchange 2007 distribution list accept external emails?](http://serverfault.com/questions/24769/how-do-i-make-an-exchange-2007-distribution-list-accept-external-emails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59x2s2s6.aspx

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);

message.Body = "This is a test e-mail message sent by an application. ";
message.Subject = "Test Email using Credentials";

NetworkCredential myCreds = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
CredentialCache myCredentialCache = new CredentialCache();        
try 
{
    myCredentialCache.Add("ContoscoMail", 35, "Basic", myCreds);
    myCredentialCache.Add("ContoscoMail", 45, "NTLM", myCreds);

    client.Credentials = myCredentialCache.GetCredential("ContosoMail", 45, "NTLM");
    client.Send(message);
    Console.WriteLine("Goodbye.");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception is raised. ");
    Console.WriteLine("Message: {0} ",e.Message);
}
```